How to align text in a table correctly?
Here's the source code:
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Total length obtained from the model for transmission lines at 150, 220 and 440 kV.}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.49\textwidth}{l l L}
\toprule
\textbf{Voltage level(kV)} & \textbf{Reported length(km)}\cite{a7} & \textbf{Inferred length(km)} \\ \midrule
150 & 2501 & 2419\\
220 & 3848 & 3648\\
400 & 3075 & 2862\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{PortugalTamanho}
\end{table}

Here's the output:

Basically i want length(km) to be directly under inferred otherwise it doesn't fit the column and goes to the next one... If i add // "length" it will go to the extreme left under "voltage level"
Also in here:
\begin{table*}[h!]
\caption{Line loading and Transferred Reactive Powers}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l l l l l l l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{From bus} & \textbf{To bus} & $\mathbf{V_{n}}$\textbf{(kV)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Emission}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Reception}} & \textbf{L}$\mathbf{_{CA}}$ (\%) & \textbf{L}$\mathbf{_{CC}}$ (\%) \\
 & & & \textbf{Q(MVAR)}$_{CA}$ &\textbf{Q(MVAR)}\cite{a7} & \textbf{Q(MVAR)}$_{CA}$ & \textbf{Q(MVAR)}\cite{a7} \\
\midrule
Fernão Ferro & Trafaria & 150 & 19.38 & 11.1 & 19.57 & 10.9 &61.6 & 57.04 \\
Fernão Ferro & Trafaria & 150 & 19.38 & 11.1 & 19.57 &  10.9 &61.6 &57.04\\
Fernão Ferro & Fogueteiro & 150 & 1.42 & 1.8 & 1.05 & 2.1  & 3.25&3.25\\ 
Fernão Ferro & Fogueteiro & 150 & 1.42 &  & 1.05 &3.25 &3.25 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{T4}
\end{table*}

This exceeds the page margins:

How can i avoid that?

Please tell us how the L column type is defined in the first example, and also why you set 0.49\textwidth instead of \columnwidth. Please also confirm that you employ the IEEEtran document class in both examples.

It would help, if you‘d replicate how both tables are embedded in text, e.g. using package blindtext or lipsum. Thank you

The OP hasn't provided any information about the document class that's in use. However, judging by the screenshots the OP posted, it appears that the IEEEtran document class (or a class that's derived from it) is supposed to be employed.

First table: Not knowing how the L column type is defined, I was unable to replicate the OP's screenshot. That said, there would seem to be no need for a tabularx environment. Just use a tabular environment and make an effort to provide a bit more visual structure to the header material. Note that it's not necessary to resort to bold-facing the header material.

Second table: Again, there's no need for a tabularx setup. Just use an ordinary tabular environment and once more provide clear visual structure to the header material. Oh, and I would load the siunitx package and use its S column type to align the numbers in column 4 thru 9 on their respective decimal markers. Once again, no need for bold-facing.





\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math clone fonts
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
% handy shortcut macro for header cells in second table:
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Total length obtained from the model for transmission lines at 150,~220 and 440 \unit{\kilo\volt}.} 
\label{PortugalTamanho}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ccc @{}}
\toprule
Voltage level & Reported length \cite{a7} & Inferred length \\
(\unit{\kilo\volt}) & (\unit{\kilo\meter}) & (\unit{\kilo\meter}) \\
\midrule
150 & 2501 & 2419 \\
220 & 3848 & 3648 \\
400 & 3075 & 2862 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\addtocounter{table}{2} % just for this example
\begin{table*}[h!]
\caption{Line loading and Transferred Reactive Powers}
\label{T4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll c *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
\toprule
From bus & To bus & 
\mytab{${V_{n}}$\\(\unit{\kilo\volt})} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Emission} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Reception} & 
{\mytab{$L_{\mathrm{CA}}$\\(\%)}} & 
{\mytab{$L_{\mathrm{CC}}$\\(\%)}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
 & & & 
 {$Q(\mathrm{MVAR})_{\mathrm{CA}}$} & {$Q(\mathrm{MVAR})$ \cite{a7}} & 
 {$Q(\mathrm{MVAR})_{\mathrm{CA}}$} & {$Q(\mathrm{MVAR})$ \cite{a7}} \\
\midrule
Fernão Ferro & Trafaria & 150 & 19.38 & 11.1 & 19.57 & 10.9 &61.6 & 57.04 \\
Fernão Ferro & Trafaria & 150 & 19.38 & 11.1 & 19.57 &  10.9 &61.6 &57.04\\
Fernão Ferro & Fogueteiro & 150 & 1.42 & 1.8 & 1.05 & 2.1  & 3.25&3.25\\ 
Fernão Ferro & Fogueteiro & 150 & 1.42 &  & 1.05 &3.25 &3.25 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[3-16] % more filler text

\end{document}



Use tabularx only have sense if you use at least one X column. The X columns wrap the contents to fit the width of the column to the available space.

You use the  L column that need the tabulary  package (and cannot be uses in tabularx environments) or is a custom column that could have defined somewhere. In the better case I guess that is really a X column left aligned, but without that definition, no one can be sure of what are you doing.

At least in the second table you use only l columns of the standard tabular (without "x") environment , where the width of the column is determined only by the cell contents, without wrapping the text, no matter the width what you set for the tabularx (with "x") environment.

Better if you not not use x.xx\textwidth to set the table width in floats of one column and \textwidth in floats of 2 columns. Use just \linewidth in both cases and you never will be wrong.

To see if a table will fit well just using some X columns or it will need something other fix, we need to know the document layout (margins, font size and so on). This can be solved illegally invading your privacy with a magical crystal  ball to see what are you doing, or a bit better, if you supply a  minimal working example (MWE), i.e. compilable code "as is", starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}, that show your document layout. You should remove from the MWE anything from the content and the preamble unrelated with the issue. As said in the comments, you can use lipsumto generate easily dummy text to show reveal the text, without having to add any real content.



There’s \columnwidth, which is better than \linewidth.

I know that exits, I know that you know much better than me the difference, so it baffles me to have to disagree that is better, at least  in the sense that aimed to transmit.  While \linewidth is always the correct full width of the float , no matter if it is in one or two column, or whether is a starred or unstarred float, in table*  obviously \columnwidth is the wrong one. Moreover,   \linewidth is also the correct in  when text space  become smaller than \columwidth (minipages, list, etc.)  whereas I don't even remember when I ever had to change \linewith to \columnwith.

I'm not sure about the objection. If you want to specify that a table in a one-column float has the same width as the column, use \columnwidth. If you specify table* you do know that you want \textwidth, don't you? Besides, when using a nonstandard class, you'd have to be confident that the redefined float environments actually set \linewidth, which is not granted.

My objection is that \linewidth is not worse because when the others two  widths are fine, usually \linewidth is exactly the same, and when this is not true (e.g., a minipage smaller that  one column) then is the only appropriate, so it is even a safer kind of wildcard. I realize that this is silly issue if you know the 3 commands,  but by ignorance or clueless some people can use/reuse code with \textwidth or \columnwidth where  is no the right length (I am sure that you saw this often), while \linewidth it would have been still correct in most cases.
